# PuTTY Option: Remote command = is sending a "preset" command that makes connexions to fail

Tags: windows, putty

Every time I open PuTTY it has the preset

```
Remote command 
env DISPLAY=`echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1":0"}'` $SHELL
```

forcing me to every time I openPuTTY, go to Remote command and delete the entry.

How can I delete that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove it and save new default settings.

[image]